# Expect condition for url that changes frequently

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

In the app there is a url and last part of this url has an id that keeps changing , so the url shows as e.g. app.com/pages/revision=**9525132131313**.
The number in the last part keeps changing. I want to apply expect based on the url. Can I somehow tell protractor to ignore the last part as I do not want to hard code this part in the spec.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have `urlContains`

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.urlContains('app.com/pages/revision'), 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks , I will give it a try